# Using and creating functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function

Not really good at MySQL and all that, but I have a project I must do and I'm trying to use a function that will use "if-exist-select" to return true or false.

I've tried running a query:

```
set @p = 'admin';
set @p1 = 'admin';
select if (exists(SELECT * FROM news_db.Users WHERE @p= u_username AND @p1 = u_password), 'true', 'false');
```

This returns true, as it is true (I have a user that is called admin and has a password admin).

Creating a procedure that goes like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `loginAuth`(`uname` VARCHAR(100), `pass` VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
if(exists(SELECT * FROM news_db.Users WHERE @uname= u_username AND @pass = u_password)) THEN
return 1;
ELSE
return 0;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

...and running it with this:

```
SET @p0='admin'; SET @p1='admin'; SELECT `loginAuth`(@p0, @p1) AS `loginAuth`;
```

returns 0.

As I said, I'm not very good at understanding this, but I cannot figure this out by myself.
If there is a simple error, please point it out to me, or if I'm doing this completely wrong, please explain how it is done, or point me in the right direction.

Also, this is a project where security is not important.

Comment: Drop the @s in the function - but nonetheless your code works for me. Please add sample data from users together with table definition.

Comment: `EXISTS ()` already returns TRUE or FALSE, so why all the IF .. ELSE ..? BTW: you shouldn't store plain user paswords.

Comment: @P.Salmon Dropping '@'s from the code managed to make it run. That was the reason I posted here, I was sure my code should work. I would have never tried to do what you said, unfortunately, so I probably would never fix it and had to work around it...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel As I said "...this is a project where security is not important.".
It meant this is a practice project to understand how the base works with information and how to use various tools and assets of the database and MySQL to learn. 
It is absolutely clear to everyone you shouldn't store nor work with plain passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to write an answer here so I could mark it as an 'answer'. #logic

@P.Salmon's answer was correct, if anyone needs it. Removing '@' signs from the variables in the function solved the issue.

This is how it should look:

```
if(exists(SELECT * FROM news_db.Users WHERE uname = u_username AND pass = u_password))
```

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in two days"
...
Neat.